# Rspec: How to test efficiently a method for each day of the year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm currently using rspec in a ruby on rails project, to test a method in a model.

In my case, I have a #set_season method which returns the season based on the current_date. So I expect this method to never return nil.

My test is passing just fine, but this seems a very ugly way to do it. I just can't see any other solution for now. But I'm trying to improve my testing skills AND the performance of the codebase that I'm testing. So any help of you girls&guys is welcome

```rb
    describe '#set_season' do
      it 'is never nil' do
        (1..12).each do |month|
          (1..31).each do |day|
            promotion.update(start_date: Time.new(2021, month, day))
            promotion.set_season
            expect(promotion.season).not_to be_nil
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Thanks !

Comment: I would argue that a test like this is too much. It should be totally fine to just test a couple of dates. Edge cases if possible, for example, the first and the last day of a year, the first and the last day of a season, a leap day, and perhaps an invalid date.

Comment: There is the `+` operator on the `Date` class if you want something nicer. Or you can put dates directly in the range. `(Date.today..Date.today+365)` Seems like your update method really wants a date anyway right? (And if you are on rails I think there is a `+1.year` opportunity.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for these answers 

Thanks to @froderik I can at least refactor my code to have something a bit more readable and optimized.

And spickermann you're right, maybe I shouldn't test all of these dates...

Comment: Another cool thing you can do with rspec is to move the `it` inside loop so you get one test case for each date. (You can also use the date in the test description.) Pretty neat and nice if 3 out of 400 dates are failing.

Comment: @froderik great advice !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close this subject, I decided to keep testing my method for each day of the year, and improved my loop with a `(Date.today..Date.today + 1.year)` as suggested.

```rb
describe '#set_season' do
  it 'is never nil' do
    (Date.today..Date.today + 1.year).each do |date|
      promotion.update(start_date: date)
      promotion.set_season
      expect(promotion.season).not_to be_nil
     end
  end
end
```